# XLS file download from webview to locally on my android device

Tags: android, webview

I have one webview inside my android application and have one .xls file on server I want to download that file into my device, this will be perform when I click on button which is inside a webview.

---

In short, I want to download .xls file from server to android device through webview's button click

---

Answer (score 0):

Set **DownloadListener** to your WebView.

Example:

```
webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
            // handle download, here we use brower to download, also you can try other approach.
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Or

```
webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
                    Request request = new Request(
                            Uri.parse(url));
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download"); 
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    dm.enqueue(request);        

        }
    });
```

Comment: Mr. Vijay, its not working I tried it thats why I posted on StackOverFlow

Comment: You have not mention what code you have tried, that's why i have posted answer.